# JSON API response approach - how to send responses while not maintaining connection

Tags: json

I'm developing a simple JSON API that will allow users to encode short movie clips into different formats.

The problem I'm struggling with right now is how to send response when encoding is done? Let's say that average encoding takes 1min. So maintaining the connection for 1min just to send response with encoded movie URL is pointless.

Client sends JSON with URL of movie clip to be encoded. Servers sends response "ok dude, hold on a sec" and ends the connection.

One approach that I figured out is to **force client to provide a callback URL**. When encoding process is finished my API can post JSON to that URL with address of encoded movie prepared for download.

Do you know of any other approaches for this scenario? I'm not much convinced about this callback url.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I would do it. I would use 3 URIs: a well-known fixed URI for uploading the original video, a temporary URI for monitoring progress, and another temporary URI for downloading the converted video. I would return a content-Location header to indicate the client where to go next:

POST /converter?output=AVI

HTTP/1.1 201 Created

Content-Location:/converter/process/12345

GET /converter/process/12345

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

X-Conversion-Status:Converting

GET /converter/process/12335

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

X-Conversion Status:Done

Content-Location:/converter/downloads/12345/myvideofile.avi

GET /converter/downloads/12345/myvideofile.avi

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

I would automatically clean up the temporary resources after a certain time.

Comment: The problem that I see here is that the connection is still maintained. In the second step (Converting) connection waits for converting results which can take up to 5 mins.